# Reindexing data in elastisearch after index change

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a field `carName` which uses some analyzer:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Text, searchAnalyzer = "myAnalyzer", analyzer = "myAnalyzer")
private String carName;
```

The `myAnalyzer` analyzer looks like this:

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "myStopwords": {
          "ignore_case": "true",
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": [
            "word1",
            "word2"
          ]
        } 
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "myTrimmer": {
          "flags": "CASE_INSENSITIVE",
          "pattern": "somepatter",
          "replacement": "somrereplacement",
          "type": "pattern_replace"
        } 
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "myAnalyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "unique",
            "myStopwords"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "myTrimmer"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now `myStopwords` will expand or can shrink.  In my database I have `CAR` entity and once someone is adding new car, it is indexed in ES as document. What do I have to do when someone changes stopwords list? Is it possible to refresh data only on ElasticSearch side, without even reading them from my database? Or due to changes in stopword list some data in index where `carName` is located could be lost during indexing - the words that were part of stopwords list for example? And in that case, unfortunatelly, I need to read cars from database again and index them again.. ?

As I understand the `analyzer` and in my case `myAnalyzer` is used during indexing process by ES, then at first sight it seems that if I change stopwords list (so it this case it is `analyzer` change), then I should reindex my cars right but maybe I am wrong ? If a car was named 'Ford King Taurus' and the `King` was not in the stopwords list, then what happens if I add `King` to stopword list.. And if `King' was in stopwords list and some documents were indexed and now is removed from that list, what happens with search then.. Would searching work fine after such mapping changes ?

I read about UpdateByQuery method that I think could be used for some similar cases to update for example part of the document. But could it be used here ? I mean.. how could I tell Elasticsearch, if it is neccessary, to refresh all carNames due to stopwords list change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same analyzer and index time and search time and you update your stop words list, both index-time and search-time analyzers will use the new stop words list right away, **however**, anything that is already indexed will not be updated, you'll need to `_update_by_query` your index in order for the new stop words to be applied.

A quick example:

If you index `Ford King Taurus` and the stop words list doesn't contain `King`, then the following tokens will be indexed: `Ford`, `King` and `Taurus`. At search time, you can find the document using either of these three terms.

Then you add `King` in the stop words list, [close and reopen your index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis) in order to refresh your analyzers. At this point, the former document with `Ford King Taurus` will not be searchable with `King` anymore since the search analyzer now ignores `King` even though the token `King` is still indexed. You could still find the document using the `standard` search analyzer and searching for `king` though, since the `king` token is still indexed.

However, if you index a new document, say, `Seat King`, then only `Seat` will be indexed and searching for `King` will yield nothing.

If you want your former document to pick up the new stop word `King` you need to either reindex the document or simply update your index in place using `_update_by_query` so the source documents get reindexed upon themselves, but with the index-time analyzer that has the new stop words list including `King`

Here is a quick summary of all the above explanations:

```
# 1. You create your index like normal
PUT test2
{
   "settings": {...},
   "mappings": {...}
}

# 2. You index "Ford King Taurus"
POST test2/_doc/1 
{
  "carName": "Ford King Taurus"
}

# 3. You can find it searching for "king"
POST test2/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "carName": "king"
    }
  }
}

# 4. You close the index, add "king" a new stop words and reopen the index
POST test2/_close
PUT test2/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "myStopwords": {
          "ignore_case": "true",
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": [
            "word1",
            "word2",
            "king"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "myAnalyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "unique",
            "myStopwords"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST test2/_open

# 5. You cannot find the document searching for "king"
POST test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "carName": {
        "query": "king"
      }
    }
  }
}
=> No results

# 6. But you can still find it using the standard search analyzer
POST test2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "carName": {
        "query": "king",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
=> 1 result

# 7. You update your index in place
POST test2/_update_by_query

# 8. None of the search queries will find anything with "king"
```

Comment: Thanks, but if u say that when King is in stopwords and from Seat King only Seat will be indexed, then what if we consider the opposite case: I will remove King from stopword list, only Seat was indexed, then also _update_by_query would be enough ? And other question - would _update_by_query approach would be valid for all kinds of index changes ?  And next one - this would be _update_by_query for matchAll query ?

Comment: The key here is that if you change the stop words list, you need to update your index in place in order for the analyzer changes to be picked up and the correct tokens to be analyzed and indexed. Just changing the stop words list doesn't change anything in the underlying index. See my reproduction above.

Comment: Ok so as I undestand _update_by_query for matchAll query will repair the index and search will be working regardless if I add King or remove King from stopwords and regardless if carName contained King in past or not right ?

Comment: Correct, either `_update_by_query` your index or reindex the data, the former being usually easier.

Comment: And if data in my db was not changed, I am only changing index definition, but not the structure of documents (I am not adding / removing any fields to documents), then this approach could be applied also for any type of such changes, not neccessarily connected with stopwords ? For example myTrimmer visible above would change, or tokenizer type or I would add / remove lowercase or unique filters

Comment: Absolutely, update by query allows you to apply any kind of changes in your analyzers to your existing data

Comment: Hello again, one additional question - can new documents arrive or be udpated by es client in the same time that I am  performing update_by_query ?

Comment: Please create a new question as this one is closed and the original question has been answered